# Vertical Inverse scrolling and Horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, web

I have visited **[the site](http://www.rleonardi.com/interactive-resume/)**. There you can see **horizontal scrolling** and in level 4, you can see the **Inverse vertical scrolling**. How can I achieve this. Just by using `css3` or using some other resources like `JS`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jquery you could do something like:

```
$(function() {

   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

      event.preventDefault();

   });

});
```

[Demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/) and 
[tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/)

or

```
window.onscroll=function() {
    var scroll = window.scrollY;
    $('article').css('left', '-' + scroll + 'px');
}
```

make sure that the css fits

```
section {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1024px;
}
article {
    width:1024px;/*same as section's height*/
    position:fixed; /*you need this to fixe the V-scroll*/
}
article p {
    float:left;
}
```

Html

```
<section>
    <article>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting </p>

    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am also searching result for Inverse vertical scrolling as I shown in example link.

Comment: it is parallax just animate the background-image